# How to know whether an image is displayed in ImageView?

Tags: android, image

I am trying to display some images in one ImageView to obtain the functionality of slide show.

I am registering an Animation Listener to the imageview for changing each picture.

When slide show is displaying, some of the images are not visible, but its memory is allocating.

I am converting images from URL to bitmap. After doing inSampleSize = 4, I am setting the bitmap to ImageView.

Why these images are not visible? the images with below 100 Kb are visible, but with 500kb has the problem.

Thanks..

### EDITED

Actually when the application launches, the images from the URL are converted to bytes and it is stored in the DB. And when we click on the Slide show button in another activity, these bytes are converted to bitmap and showed by the ImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry all,
Finally I figured out the problem.

I increase the duration of animation according to image size.
Now all images are displaying fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are larger than a few kB, it is best practice to use a ContentProvider rather than loading these images directly from storage.  This may be your problem.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html#querying

Give this a read and try the ContentResolver.openInputStream and Cursor.getBlob() method of retrieving images, and see if it works any better for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: actually these images are stored in the DB as bytes. And when the time comes to show these images, the bytes are converted to bitmap and showed by the ImageView. How can I use content provider in thise scenario?

Comment: Use the same idea, Cursor.getBytes with the URI of the resource you are trying to access, then convert it to a bitmap and display it in your imageView